# How to download a generated captcha using mechanize?

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to build a sort-of client a blog platform in my country, but the blog platform has an in-house built captcha generation.

The problem is that the CAPTCHA is built as such so that a new image is generated every time there is a GET request. So suppose the captcha image URL is this: http://example.com/randomcaptcha.aspx?someparams-that-are-always-the-same

Even when I open the above link in Firefox and hit refresh (which shows the JPG image only), I'm presented with a different image every time I refresh.

The problem arises because when mechanize downloads the entire web page, it also downloads the image during that request (or rather, it follows the randomcaptcha.aspx link). So when I try to download the image again, I need to issue another GET request to grab the image and download it - and at this moment the image has changed.

How would I solve this problem?

Thank you.

EDIT the code currently is this:

```
browser.open("http://www.example.com/registration.aspx") #this contains the randomcaptcha.aspx url in img src
#then we have a regex to find the url of the image, say the variable is url
with open("captcha.jpg", "wb") as file:
    file.write(browser.open_novisit(url).read())
```

At this time the downloaded captcha.jpg file is already different from the one presented on the registration page. I used the software called Fiddler to see that - there are definitely 2 GET requests being issued for the `randomcaptcha.aspx` url.

EDIT #2 Solved: My bad. The captcha URL was incorrect.

Comment: Post your current code. Mechanize shouldn't do this.

Comment: Added, thanks. Hope it clears it up a bit.

Comment: How do you know that the image has changed once you've downloaded it?

Comment: Because I can see it in Fiddler. The first time it downloads one image, the second time another. And plus when I enter the text in my application, the server's response is "Incorrect code entered".

Comment: That's really odd. I don't recall Mechanize ever doing this to me.

Comment: Yep, never mind me, I'm retarded. The captcha URL was incorrect - the server replaced the & with &amp;, and I forgot to put it back to &.

Comment: So how long have you been debugging this one for?

Comment: Honestly? 4 days. I am not ashamed to say that. It took me 4 days before A FRIEND said "dude, try replacing the `&amp;` with `&`".

Comment: Dang, you beat my record by two. Well, at least you got it. Good luck!

Comment: Might be good to post the solution as an answer so this doesn't show up in the Unanswered tab.